# Regular expression with grep

Tags: linux, grep

I want to extraxt the id in the following string using grep with the options -oP.

amazon.com [id: 4083138926]

I tried multiple expressions and the best I could come up with is
[0-9]+, which doesn't work if amazon.com was something else that contains numbers. I tried lookarounds with no much success. I only need to extract the Id, i.e. 4083138926.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\[id: )[0-9]+(?=\])'
```

It will only extract numbers inside `[id: ...]` via [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only `grep`, then the most robust approach is probably to chain two `grep -o` commands: one to remove everything before the `[` so that you know you only have one number to worry about, and one to grab that number. For example:

```
echo 'amazon.com [id: 4083138926]' \
| grep -o '\[id: [0-9]*\]' \
| grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*'
```